# how to check list before adding items?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of [i,j] values:

```
lst = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4],[4,6]]
#[1,2] means that i=1 and j=2
```

and add new elenemt `[a,b]`, for example `[6,1]`, how can I add values to my lst by condition

(add element `[a,b]` only if `[b,j]` does not exists in a set)

So element `[6,1]` should not be added, because `[1,2]` and `[1,3]` is already in the list

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you actually mean, if `[b, j]` is not in the list?

Comment: Just iterate the list and compare with the components of each element, or if performance is more critical, create sets of all i and j and check those.

Comment: @tobias_k right, we should add elements only if it's second index (in [6,1]  it's  1) doesn't equal to any of first indices in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just iterate the list and check whether for `any` of the items `(i,j)` in the list, `i` is the same as `b` in the item `(a,b)` you want to add. (At least that's how I understood your condition, but if the condition is slightly different, this should be easy to adapt accordingly.)

```
def cond_add(lst, item):
    a, b = item
    if not any(i == b for (i, j) in lst):
        lst.append(item)

lst = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4],[4,6]]
cond_add(lst, [6,1])
cond_add(lst, [6,5])
print(lst)
```

If you want to add multiple elements, it would pay to create a `set` from the first elements, so you can do the check in constant time for each individual item. (You could do the same for adding individual elements, but you'd have to update the set after each item.)

```
def cond_add_many(lst, items):
    first = set(i for (i, j) in lst)
    for (a,b) in items:
        if b not in first:
            lst.append((a,b))
            first.add(a)

lst = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,4],[4,6]]
cond_add_many(lst, [[6,1], [6,5], [7,6]])
print(lst)
```

Afterwards, in both cases, `lst` is `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 4], [4, 6], (6, 5)]`

Answer (score 2):

From a readability / maintainability POV I usually prefer to have a custom class handling the invariants instead:

```
# XXX poor naming but I don't know enough of the context
class Container(object): 
    def __init__(self, *initvals):
        self._values = []
        self._keys = set()
        for pair in initvals:
            self.add(pair)

    def add(self, pair):
        if pair[1] in self._keys:
            raise ValueError("second item of pair '{}' already set".format(pair))
        self._keys.add(pair[0])
        self._values.append(pair)

    def values(self):
        # returns a copy so no one accidentally messes
        # with internal state
        return self._values[:]

c = Container((1,2), (1,3), (3,4), (4,6))
c.add((8, 9))
assert (8, 9) in c.values(), "(8,9) not correctly added"

try:
    c.add((6, 1))
except ValueError as e:
    #print "got error {} when adding (6,1)".format(e)
    pass
else:
    assert False, "adding (6, 1) should have raised a ValueError"

print c.values()
```